# Difference between CGAffineTransformMakeRotation and CGAffineTransformRotate

Tags: swift, core-animation

I am starting to play around with Swift's core animation methods and am trying to figure out the difference between these two methods.  I succeed in making a square rotate using CGAffineTransformRotate, but I wanted to know what the other was used for.

My best guess is that the CGAffineTransformRotate is performed on something that already has rotated, as it has a parameter that accepts a transform.

Comment: Did you read the docs? I feel like they're pretty clear.

Answer (score 7):

`CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( angle )` creates a new affine transform matrix that represents rotation of a fixed angle.

`CGAffineTransformRotate( t, angle )` creates an new affine transformation matrix by applying a rotation to an existing affine transform.